Select2: "Cannot read properties of undefined" when prepending/unshifting data on scroll up
I'm using Select2 and trying to implement a feature where new data is prepended or unshifted to the dropdown options when the user scrolls up. However, I'm encountering the errors "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_resultId')" and when I select that prepended option shows error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')".
    let isLoading = false;
    function loadMoreData() {
      if (isLoading || !isAjaxEnabled || page <= 1) {
        return; 
      }
    
      isLoading = true;
    
      $.ajax({
        url: `${apiHost}example`,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
          text: term,
          page: page
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('Received new data:', data);
    
          const $resultsList = $('#select2-multi-select-results');
          const newOptions = data.results.map(item => {
            console.log('Creating new option:', item);
            return $('<li class="select2-results__option" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="' + item.id + '">' + item.text + '</li>');
          });
          $resultsList.prepend(newOptions);
          console.log('Prepended new options:', newOptions);

          $('.multi-select2').select2('data', data);
          console.log('Updated Select2 data');
    
          isLoading = false;
        },
        error: function() {
          console.error('Error loading more data');
          isLoading = false; 
        }
      });
    }

    $('.multi-select2').on('select2:open', function() {
        const $dropdown = $('#select2-multi-select-results');
        $dropdown.on('scroll', function() {
          if ($dropdown.scrollTop() < 50 && isAjaxEnabled) {
            loadMoreData();
          }
        });

Error cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_resultId')
select2.js

Error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
select2.js

I've tried various approaches, but I'm still getting the errors. I suspect it might be related to the data structure or how I'm handling the Select2 results.
How can I ensure that the _resultId and id properties are defined in the data I'm receiving?
What's the correct way to prepend or unshift new data to the Select2 options?
Are there any specific configuration settings or event handlers I need to consider for this functionality?

There's no _resultId in the code you posted. Which line is getting that error?

I think the _resultId is an internal property used by Select2. Those two errors appear within the Select2.js file.

Does the stack trace of the error show where in your code it's being called from?

loadModeData() requires a params argument. You're calling it with no argument in the select2:open event handler.

Assume the params variable doesn't exist and is simply a global variable. The data exists, and I'm attempting to prepend options when the scrolling action occurs. The options are indeed prepended, but I'm encountering errors: _resultId and when i select it shows error id are undefined, even though the id exists on the option element.

What do you see in the output from console.log('Received new data:', data);?

its the data object contains results and pagination
